# Is there any way to "gift" apps in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

In Canada, you cannot purchase apps with a gift card.   Other than purchasing a prepaid Visa/Mastercard, is there any other way to give apps as a gift?

If anyone can explain this stupid policy, I'd appreciate it too.

Answer (score 2):

"Official" response from Apple (from [here](http://www.ipodtouchanswers.com/touch-life/using-itunes-gift-cards-on-the-app-store/)) on why gift cards cannot be used to purchase apps in Canada:

> Due to tax laws and commerce restrictions for software in Canada, customers residing in Canada may only purchase games and applications using a credit card.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the case for all App Stores. You can't add an app to a wish list either. It's frustrating. Fingers crossed that it will improve -- the App Store is gradually getting better.